# Is there an API for AJAX responses in Grails

Tags: ajax, grails

Is there an API for returning a result from a AJAX call. Something where you could set the errorCode, data value, error messages, etc ... Right now it seems to me you can return anything in any form and your client needs to figure it out.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an API as that's a contract you should define with your REST/AJAX clients. Taking a page from the old ExtJS playbook it's common to see something like this.

```
{
  'error': true/false,
  'messages': ['message one', 'message two'],
  'data': {
    .. other data goes here ..
  }
}
```

This should help you design your own contact. Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes that is exactly something like that I was expecting. Things I can imagine we should have are flash messages and error messages. What about return codes? should we populate response.status with codes like 200 and 500. What should be the value in what circumstances. I was hoping to find an well defined API for that. How does rest deal with this?

Comment: In regards to the status codes that's more of a REST design question and this will help you understand when you should set the HTTP status and to what. http://restpatterns.org/HTTP_Status_Codes

Comment: Does jquery ajax or angular $http or promises listen to the response code to decide what function to execute (success, failure). What about the argument of those functions, how are they set?